# clarification on the function declaration of ..<

Tags: swift, function, for-loop

I'm currently learning the range operator `..<` in swift. I understand how ..< works on the surface, but what I really want to know is how `..<` works in a bit more detail.

Below is a copy of the `..<` function declaration. I have found apple documentation on `Comparable`, `CountableRange`, but have not been able to find any documentation on `Bound`, `_Strideable`, `Bound.Stride`. So could someone please tell me how I can find out more about those classes? Or if it is not possible to find documentations on those classes, could you please explain what they actually does?

```
for index in 0..<2 {
    print(index)
}
```

[image]

```
func ..<<Bound where Bound : _Strideable & Comparable, Bound.Stride : Integer>(minimum: Bound, maximum: Bound) -> CountableRange<Bound>
```

Comment: Strideable it is not a class it is a Protocol and Stride it is the associated Type

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for your comment. Just wondering if there is a way to find out more about them?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/strideable and http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/protocol/Strideable/

Comment: @LeoDabus I have looked through the two resources, but there does not seem to be a type called `Bound` in neither. Am I doing this wrong or `Bound` indeed could not be found?

Comment: `Bound` is the placeholder type in the generic function.

Comment: http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/CountableRange/

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for introducing me to swiftdoc.org. it will definitly be a valuable tool for everyone who is learning swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
func ..<<Bound where Bound : _Strideable & Comparable, Bound.Stride : Integer>(minimum: Bound, maximum: Bound) -> CountableRange<Bound>
```

defines a generic function `..<` which uses `Bound` as the placeholder type and places some restrictions on that placeholder type.  Specifically `Bound` must be both `_Strideable` and `Comparable` and `Bound.Stride` (which is an associated type defined in `_Strideable`) must be `Integer`

So... it defines a function `..<` which takes two arguments of the same type which must be strideable and comparable and the stride associated type must be `Integer`

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! hopefully with more experience and time, i can start understand complex function declaration on my own.